# Get data from a text file while i have the text file open(active window) and writing to it and not saving it

Tags: ruby

```
class ReadFile
      attr_accessor :filepath, :condigos

      def initialize
        @filepath = filepath
        @condigos = false
      end

      def reader(filepath)
        while condigos == false
          File.foreach(filepath) do |line|
            puts line
            sleep(5)
          end
        end
      end
end
```

require_relative 'reader_class'

reader = ReadFile.new

reader.reader("text.txt")

Comment: Select it and format it as code, or indent an additional four spaces, or wrap in triple-backticks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, though.

Comment: Thank you for the format guidance!  In every IDE i think there is this thing where when you type some code, a little pop up window appears with some choices. I want to create the same thing while using sublime for example. When i type certain string/words, i want a little pop up window to be shown with some options.

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: You want to develop an intellisense plugin for... Sublime? Are the packages currently available (no idea what's available now; switched off Sublime several years ago), e.g., Sublime Codeintel, insufficient? Or you specifically want to create your own? Or...?

Comment: I am a new developer  with little experience and i want to create my own for learning purposes. I am doing a bootcamp at the moment but i have been watching tutorials for some time now. :D

Comment: I see. Editor development is relatively difficult. Plugging in to an existing editor is pretty hard too. The source for several editors is open, so you can see how they do it--it's decidedly non-trivial.

Comment: hmm, i don't want to use sublime for this process. Let me elaborate: I am writing into a .txt file. By typing certain string (e.g. ' Venus: ' ) into that file, then the ruby script lets say should recognize that string as a method call. As soon as it recognizes it, it pops up a little window with some options, for example to open a certain app or something like that.

Comment: “A little window” that pops up while you’re editing a file—that’s an editor.

Comment: You are correct. I have been processing it from the  "inside - out" and could not see the connection. I do not think that is 100% an Editor but pretty sure that it belongs to that category. Thank you for your input, i have to approach this as if it was an Editor.